# Typescript generic http service with angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to create some kind of generic http service in angular + ts, where I provide model type and it should be able connect to corresponding endpoint.

I have following working solution:

```
type Type<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

public getList<T>(c: Type<T>): Observable<T[]> {
    const service = this.getService<T>(c);
    return service.getList();
  }

private getService<T>(c: Type<T>) {
     const match = this.serviceMapping.find(i => c === i.type);
     if (!match) {
        throw new Error('No service registered for type ' + c.name);
     }
     
      return match.service;
  }
```

I have created mapping object to map provided objects to services

```
    this.serviceMapping = [
      {
        type: Customer, // object class
        service: customerService, // injected singleton instance of http service
      },
     ]
```

and getList is called from component e.g.:

```
genericService.getList<Customer>(Customer).subscribe(...)
```

This is working fine and service returns results, but I do not like that I have to provide Customer type as method parameter. I would like to remove it from method parameters and leave parameters only for request related data (query parameters, body, ...).
Is it somehow possible?

I would like to use it like this:

```
genericService.getList<Customer>().subscribe(res => this.customers = res);
genericService.getById<Customer>(customerId).subscribe(...)
genericService.create<Customer>(customerData).subscribe(...)
genericService.getList<Foo>(customerData).subscribe(res => this.foos = res;)
genericService.getList<Bar>(customerData).subscribe(res => this.bars = res)
```

(Of course that I will make sure that every service will provide those methods. This should handle default CRUD operations).

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand the question here. It looks like `Customer` is a static member of whatever class you are in. If you don't want to pass it as a parameter simply remove it from the argument list

Comment: Can this service class have multiple type calls within the same component( let's say other than `Customer`). This all seems unnecessarily complicated. Even if you do, you should have multiple class instances in your components(instead of generic class)

Comment: Can you share the code of service? I understand from the question that you don't want to pass the type to the methods and keep the parameters of data.

Comment: @sinanspd I updated question to make it more obvious that I want to use multiple different types

Answer (score 0):

As of typescript 2.8, this is possible. You can get the return type of the function.
Refer to this merged PR - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21847

you can create a common method which passes the function as a parameter and check for the type.

Comment: Could you please explain this a little more? How could I compare generic type T with class?